# Why is this greedy operator ? being generous

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

My regex is:

```
/((\&sll\=|@)(?<latitude>-?\d{1,3}\.\d*),(?<longitude>-?\d{1,3}\.\d*))?/
```

I would like to match all 3 of the following strings:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&time=&date=&ttype=&q=21421+N.+Mdddoe+St.+Moickoe,+MI+48162&sll=77.070743,-23.1193&sspn=0.030456,0.033474&ie=UTF8&t=k&z=16&iwloc=addr&om=1
https://www.google.com/maps/place/173s10+N+Ladddel+ddddk+Dr,+Lddddd+sssss+Place,+Lfadfss,+MI+48152/@43.4353453,-45.4166187,848m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x8824b2772a3b2b7f:0x677087e29a57bf25?hl=en
https://www.google.com/maps/dir//57+bbbbb+Street,+adasfsf,+CT+02424
```

In the case of the first 2, latitude and longitude named groups should have the latitude and longitude values and in the case of the 3, the regex should return a match, but the named groups should be undefined.

If I remove the `?` once or none operator, it matches the first 2 and has the correct values in latitude and longitude. Obviously won't match the third though. On the other hand, with the `?` it matches all three but doesn't fill the named groups.

How can I get my desired result? Why doesn't putting a `?` around the whole thing mean match it if its there, if not, don't?

Comment: 1. Using [this kind of trick to parse url](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/parsing-urls-in-javascript) with basic code is IMO from far more elegant to obtain what you want. 2. Named captures don't exist in Javascript (except if you use the XRegExp library). 3. `&` and `=` aren't special characters in a regex pattern and don't need to be escaped.

Comment: 1. That's way overkill for a one-off grabbing a quick latitude, longitude. But thanks, anyway. \n 2. Node.js 10 and above has named captures. 3. Ah!

Comment: Anyway, I was overthinking it a lot, because the best thing was just to match them individually, and check if there was a match or not before getting the groups properties...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this out, myself.

First of all, to get my desire result, just use the global option. See here: https://regex101.com/r/x9kr3R/1 It matches at every single character, but the named groups are also populated so I can read those off.

Then, that explains why it doesn't work the other way, since it already found a match at the very first character, it doesn't continue on to find the match where the `?` group will be fulfilled. So that greedy means greedy locally not greedy globally is one way of thinking about it... That is, when the first match is found, within the context of that match, it is greedy.